# MKMapView not full screen with TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

I am making a simple app to display various things and on one of the tabs I like for it to display a map of your current location.  It seems for some reason, even though in Xcode the controller is stretched towards the bottom, it looks like when run in the simulator, an area of unused space and I am unsure why.

I have the following code:

```
@interface MapViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   _map.delegate = self;
   _map.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
   _map.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate; 
   MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 200, 200);
   [self.map setRegion:[self.map regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

[image: Xcode Map View] [image: Simulator View]

Comment: Set the proper constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the constraints.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I heard about the constraints but had little idea how to use them.  What are they for, I mean, why is it necessary when I "drew" what I wanted in IB?

Comment: So‐called Auto Layout. you can define constraints to control how your user interface adapts immediately to any size changes. See also https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/